# Simple 2-connected graph with diameter 2 and 2n-5 edges

Tags: graph-theory

For each $n \ge 5$ find a simple 2-connected graph with $n$ vertices and diameter 2, and with $2n-5$ edges.

I had this as homework, and gave the following solution, which is obviously wrong:

We first construct the graph $(A_1 \cup A_1)*A_{n-4}$ where $K_1$ is the graph with one vertex and $A_{n-4}$ is the graph with $n-4$ vertices and no edges.
The resulting graph has $n-4+2=n-2$ vertices and $2(n-4)=2n-8$ edges, so we need two more vertices and three edges.
My solution was to link them to two central vertices: if $v,u$ the new ones and $x,y$ two random central ones we add the edges $(x,u),(u,v),(v,y)$.
This, while it makes the graph have the desired number of edges, makes the diameter 3.
Choosing the graph $(A_1 \cup A_1)*A_{n-2}$ gives $2n-4$ edges with diameter 2.

Is my approach correct? What am i missing?

Answer (score 1):

Actually found the answer as i was writing the question down. 
Just use the same approach but connect the new vertices $(u,v)$ with the outer 2 vertices in the same way. Now the diameter is 2 and you still get the desired number of edges.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would just start with a central point and connect the other $n-1$ points to it.  That gives the right number of vertices, $n-1$ edges, and diameter $2$.  Now just add $n-4$ more edges somewhere between the outer points.  That cannot increase the diameter and won't make it $1$ as long as you don't make a complete graph.  You can count edges to show the graph is not complete.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to edit the problem (just added it to the title) that the graph must be 2-connected, and your graph is only 1-connected. Thank you for answering though!

Comment: I missed the 2-connected requirement.  Your answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I started with the case n=5, the graph C5 is 2-connected and has size m=2(5)-5 = 5.
Let w be a vertex in C5 (deg(w)=2), I added a new vertex v and joined it to w and to one of the two vertices that are not adjacent to w. This new graph is still 2-connected, has diameter 2 and size m=2(6)-5=7. If you continue this process (adding again a new vertex and join it to w and to a vertex nos adyacent to w in the original C5) you will always obtain a graph with diam=2 and m=2(n)-5.